# numpy random array values between -1 and 1

Tags: python, numpy

what is the best way to create a NumPy array of a given `size` with values randomly and uniformly spread between `-1` and `1`?

I tried `2*np.random.rand(size)-1`

Comment: It should work.

Comment: Your way seems fine to me.

Comment: What's the problem with what you tried?

Comment: Thank you. You are right, it works. I was looking for a numpy function that would give me such an array without the x2 trick.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure. Try:

```
s = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size)
```

reference: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html

Answer (score 1):

In your solution the `np.random.rand(size)` returns random floats in the half-open interval [0.0, 1.0)

this means `2 * np.random.rand(size) - 1` returns numbers in the half open interval [0, 2) - 1 := [-1, 1), i.e. range including -1 but not 1.

If this is what you wish to do then it is okay.

But, if you wish to generate numbers in the open interval (-1, 1), i.e. **between** -1 and 1 and hence **not including** either -1 or 1, may I suggest the following -

```
from numpy.random import default_rng
rg = default_rng(2)

size = (5,5)

rand_arr = rg.random(size)
rand_signs = rg.choice([-1,1], size)

rand_arr = rand_arr * rand_signs

print(rand_arr)
```

I have used the new suggested Generator per numpy, see link https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/index.html#quick-start

Answer (score 0):

I can use `numpy.arange`:

```
import numpy as np

print(np.arange(start=-1.0, stop=1.0, step=0.2, dtype=np.float))
```

The `step` parameter defines the size and the uniformity in the distribution of the elements.

Answer (score -1):

100% working Code:

```py
a = np.random.uniform(-1,1)
print(a)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: your not answering the question of `size`. Also, the correct with `np.random.uniform` was already posted in 2019