# Transformed Dirichlet array with range [-1,1] in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, transformation, dirichlet

A random vector sampled from the Dirichlet distribution contains values that fall in the **domain [0,1] and they sum to 1**. In numpy it can be programmed like this for a vector size of 5:

```
x = numpy.random.dirichlet(np.ones(5))
```

Instead, I would like a random vector that contains values that are **[-1,1] and sum to 1**, which [I was told](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/487526/is-there-a-statistical-distribution-whose-values-are-bounded-1-1-and-sum-to) can be achieved by transforming the Dirichlet generated `x` vector as `y = 2x -1`

Below is an attempt at this transformation. The script doesn't work properly however because `y` doesn't sum to 1 as needed. How can it be fixed, or could it be that `y = 2x -1` does not do what they said?

```
x = numpy.random.dirichlet(np.ones(5))
y = 2*x -1
print(x, np.sum(x))
print(y, np.sum(y))
```

which outputs:

```
[0.0209344  0.44791586 0.21002354 0.04107336 0.28005284] 1.0
[-0.9581312  -0.10416828 -0.57995291 -0.91785327 -0.43989433] -3.0000000000000004
```

Comment: What do the printouts actually show?

Comment: edited in the output. the sum is a negative integer, scaled to the target number of elements (size 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `y=1/(dimension/3)-2*x`. That worked for me.

Comment: if `dimension=2`, though, this answer can give an element that is greater than 1, which crosses the desired bounds. Besides that, all `dimensions>2` work better than any other answer, so far

Answer (score 3):

The thing is that interval `[0, 1]` can have one and the only one linear map to interval `[-1, 1]` which is actualy a map `x -> 2x - 1`. But it can't guarantee that your sum will be stable. A reason can be seen in these observations:

```
np.sum(x)
0.9999999999999999
np.sum(2*x)
1.9999999999999998
np.sum(2*x-1)
-3.0
```

As you can see, the last sum doesn't decrease by 1 as expected. It actually decreases by 5 because every of 5 items were decreased by 1.

Comment: so the script is right but the suggested math transformation is wrong?

Comment: Yes, I agree. An article says that you can't get sum required, it was mentioned in a second part of Sectus's answer in StackExchange

Comment: any alternatives? besides those shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63891845/random-numpy-array-whose-values-are-between-1-and-1-and-sum-to-1/63895047#63895047

Comment: We were discussing a linear maps only. Don't know about other types like exponential or smth.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the answers on stats.stackexchange explains: there is only one way that you can map the variables of a Dirichlet distribution to [-1,1] *while* keeping the sum equal to 1. This is when the dimension is 3 and when you use y=1-2x

```
import numpy
numpy.random.seed(seed = 1)
x = numpy.random.dirichlet(alpha = numpy.ones(3), size = 1)
y = 1-2*x
print(x, numpy.sum(x))
print(y, numpy.sum(y))
```

which prints:

```
[[2.97492728e-01 7.02444212e-01 6.30601451e-05]] 1.0000000000000002
[[0.40501454 -0.40488842  0.99987388]] 0.9999999999999998
```

Comment: It is not dimension, it's size.

Comment: @mathfux the size of the alpha vector is the dimension of the output variable. Or at least, that is according to the terminology in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.dirichlet.html) *"Draw size samples of dimension k from a Dirichlet distribution"*